# How to convert .xls file to .dbf?

Tags: iphone, sql, ios, sqlite

I have a xls file with a bunch of data in a table.  I want to be able to use sql with this in my ios app.  How can I get it to a .db file or whatever I need for my app?  Do I have to manually make the sql tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Export the xls file to .csv text file.  Create a .db file using sqlite at the command line. Create the tables at the command line.  Set the sqlite separator to "," and import your .csv file. Add the .db file to your xcode project.  link to the sqlite3 framework in xcode.

Or Core Data might be easier.

Comment: where can i find the .db file that is made?

Comment: if you want to create a file called "myDatabase.db", at the command line type "sqlite3 myDatabase.db" and the .db file will be created in your current directory